Coveo Atomic React wrapper - Use default sort on page load but change sort to Relevancy automatically on search
We have a number of search pages where we want the default Sort, when the user first hits the page and hasn't entered a query, to be alphabetical or date order; but when the user enters a search query, the Sort should automatically change to relevance. This seems like intuitive user experience, but as it works now, it stays Alphabetical until the user manually changes the Sort option.
I was pointed to this article about integrating with headless but this would require completely rebuilding our search pages, plus as we have a headless NextJs project I'm not sure if using the regular non-React components is even possible and if it is it would be a huge lift, so I'm looking here for a solution with the React Atomic components - something compatible with the code I already have without completely starting from scratch
Here is an example of our Atomic React code. The Sort dropdown populates in the order the AtomicSortExpression elements are placed in the code and always defaults to the first item. Is there any way to make the sort automatically update to Relevancy when the user searches for something?
<div className={cn('b-container g-grid top-search-component')}>
  <AtomicExternal>
    <Text
      tag="h1"
      className="searchResultsHeader"
      field={props?.fields?.searchResultsHeader}
    />
    <AtomicSearchBox>
      <AtomicSearchBoxQuerySuggestions maxWithQuery={5} />
      <AtomicSearchBoxRecentQueries maxWithQuery={5} />
    </AtomicSearchBox>
    <AtomicRefineToggle />
  </AtomicExternal>
</div>
<div className={cn('b-container g-grid inner-shadow')}>
  <AtomicSearchInterface
    engine={searchEngine}
    language="en"
    languageAssetsPath="/lang/search"
    iconAssetsPath="/assets/search"
  >
    <AtomicBreadbox />
    <div className="results__container">
      <div className="topbar">
        <AtomicQuerySummary enableDuration={false} />
        <AtomicSortDropdown>
          <!-- THIS USES THE FIRST SORT EXPRESSION AS THE DEFAULT ON PAGE LOAD, BUT WE NEED IT TO PUT RELEVANCY FIRST WHEN THERE IS A QUERY -->
          <AtomicSortExpression
            label="Alphabetical A-Z"
            expression="searchtitle ascending"
          />
          <AtomicSortExpression
            label="Alphabetical Z-A"
            expression="searchtitle descending"
          />
          <AtomicSortExpression
            label={labels.sortNewest}
            expression="searchdate descending"
          />
          <AtomicSortExpression
            label={labels.sortOldest}
            expression="searchdate ascending"
          />
          <AtomicSortExpression label={labels.sortRelevance} expression="relevancy" />
        </AtomicSortDropdown>
      </div>
      <div className="results">
        <AtomicDidYouMean />
        <AtomicResultList
          fieldsToInclude={settings.fieldsToInclude ?? ''}
          display="list"
          imageSize="large"
          template={templateFunction}
        />
        <div className="pagination">
          <AtomicPager numberOfPages={4} />
          <AtomicResultsPerPage choicesDisplayed="10, 20, 30" />
        </div>
        <div className="status">
          <AtomicQueryError />
          <AtomicNoResults />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </AtomicSearchInterface>
</div>


The solution that I found was to modify the request body.
preprocessRequest: (request: any, clientOrigin: any) => {
  if (clientOrigin === 'searchApiFetch') {
    request.body = getUpdatedRequestBody(
      request,
      settings,
      searchConfig?.source,
      '@searchtitle ascending'
    );
  }

  return request;
},


export const getUpdatedRequestBody = (
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any, @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
  request: any,
  settings: SearchComponentSettings,
  source?: string[],
  sortCriteria?: string
): string => {
  /// request body modifications not relevant to this issue.... ///

  // if there's NO query and there's no selected sort criteria...
  if (
    (!body.q || body.q === '') &&
    (!body.sortCriteria || body.sortCriteria == 'relevancy') &&
    sortCriteria
  ) {
    body.sortCriteria = sortCriteria;
  }

  return JSON.stringify(body);
};

This effectively changes the behavior of "relevancy" when there is no query. If there is no query, relevancy will be overriden with the specified sort order (which is fine because "relevancy" doesn't really mean anything when there is no query), but if there is a query, it will function as expected. The other sort options are unaffected and work as expected. The only downside is that this solution is not able to change the selected sort option in the dropdown, so it will say "Relevance" while sorting alphabetically. It would be preferable to make it actually show "Alphabetical" in the sort dropdown, but it is still an improved user experience and works in a logical way

